# Markdown to html, include a link

Tags: html, gulp, markdown

It is possible to get files from markdown to html using [gulp-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-markdown).

But still it's not very helpful if the links to a stylesheet can not be automatically included.

### Minimal example of what it's meant:

**Markdown File** example.md

```
# MD files are simple to write
 * then it could be interesting to use them to write blog-posts with a minimal formatting
 * New bullet
```

**After `gulp-markdown`** example.html

```
<h1 id="md-files-are-simple-to-write">MD files are simple to write</h1>
<ul>
<li>then it could be interesting to use them to write blog-posts with a minimal formatting</li>
<li>New bullet</li>
</ul>
```

**Expected**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='path/to/style.css'/>
</head>
    <h1 id="md-files-are-simple-to-write">MD files are simple to write</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>then it could be interesting to use them to write blog-posts with a minimal formatting</li>
    <li>New bullet</li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

---

#### Any ideas where can I look at or how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://marked.js.org/#/USING_PRO.md#renderer

You can do a kind of template by adding a custom renderer:

```
// myHtml is the HTML you already made
let myTemplate = new markdown.Renderer()
myTemplate.html(someHtml) {
  return `<html><head></head><body>${someHtml}</body></html>`
}
let fullHtml = marked(myHtml, {renderer: myTemplate}
```